# Sorting an array of decimal & whole numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, decimal

I can't seem to figure this one out.

```
var arr = [2.62, 111.05, 1.05]
arr.sort();
```

This returns [1.05, 111.05, 2.62], but I'm expecting [1.05, 2.62, 111.05].

How can this be achieved? I've read a bit about writing a custom sort to split the "decimal" but haven't managed to have any success.

Comment: not familiar with javascript but the sorting seems as if the elements are strings rather than float

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default sorting is alphabetically. You need to pass a function to the `sort` method

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){return a-b;});
```

Comment: If it still does not work, try this: arr.sort(function(a,b){return a > b;});

Comment: @s.n that's incorrect, `>` will compare `a` and `b` as strings and hence still alphabetically

Answer (score 9):

The [`sort` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) compares the items as strings by default. You can specify a comparer function to make the comparison any way you like. This will compare the items as numbers:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){ return a - b; });
```

Note: All numbers in Javascript a double precision floating point numbers, even if they happen to contain an integer value, so integer values and decimal values are not treated differently.

Answer (score 2):

This is the normal behavior for `Array.sort()` when it isn't given a comparator function. Try this:

```
var arr = [2.62, 111.05, 1.05];
arr.sort(function(a,b) { return a-b; });
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> If compareFunction is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in Unicode code point order. For example, "Cherry" comes before "banana". In a numeric sort, 9 comes before 80, but because numbers are converted to strings, "80" comes before "9" in Unicode order.